# Is it possible to divide each column value of a table by each column value of another table in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table A with these columns: site_name, **monthly_productibility**. I also have a table B with these columns: site_name, **monthly_production**.

I want to divide the column monthly_productibility (**table A**) by the column monthly_production (**table B**).

When I try the DIVIDE function (fast measure or DAX function):

```
DIVIDE(
    SUM('TABLE_B'[monthly_production]),
    COUNTA('TABLE_A'[monthly_productibility]))
```

*The results are just so wrong, I tried different formulas but still doesn't work and I want to merge the tables only if I am obligated to do so (I am more into a generic approach).*

Comment: Are the tables related? How is the relationship between both tables?

Comment: Table relation and cardinality is important. Let us know the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a measure in tableA:

```
test = DIVIDE(SUM(tableA[monthly_productibility]), SUM(TableB[monthly_production]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the result, it is :

```
DIVIDE(
    SUM('TABLE_B'[monthly_production]),
    AVERAGE('TABLE_A'[monthly_productibility]))
```